# HTML external javascript load another javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

my problem is this.

I want place content of javascript "c.php" or "d.php" between div tags in "a.php".

In file "b.php" i choose which content of javascript move where.

example:
i want move result of "c.php" between div tags with id in "a.php".
so code will look this

`<div id="top">test c</div>`

please help me how to move javascript c.php and d.php to specified place in a.php and execute it to document.write content on place where i want. if i look to html code i see script in place but this script not write text what i want here. thanks.

file "a.php" (can edit)

```
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="mid"></div>
  <div id="bot"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="b.php"></script>
</body>
```

file b.php (can edit)

```
<? if($file=="c" and $position=="top"){ ?> 
var se = document.createElement("script");
se.src = "c.php";
se.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementById("top").appendChild(se);
<? }else{ ?>
var se = document.createElement("script");
se.src = "d.php";
se.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementById("bot").appendChild(se);
<? } ?>
```

file c.php (can't edit)

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');    
?>
document.write("test c");
```

file d.php (can't edit)

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');    
?>
document.write("test d");
```

EDIT:

in simple i want do this result:

```
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="top"><script type="text/javascript" src="c.php"></script></div>
  <div id="mid"></div>
  <div id="bot"><script type="text/javascript" src="d.php"></script></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="b.php"></script>
</body>
```

with script b.php create or move script c.php and d.php to this div elements and run it's code, which document.write show text in place where they created/moved :-/ it is not real?

Comment: There is a lot wrong here. For starters in your b.php if, `$file="c" and $position="top"` use the single equals sign which assigns values, you probably want to compare.  Also, those variables need to be passed some values before the comparison.  But rather than pick apart everything wrong with this code, sorry to be blunt, I think your approach isn't ideal.  You say you can't edit some files so you may be locked into a system...but b.php can be simplified, use 2 functions instead of an if and then just call the one you want from a.php.

Comment: double equals fixed, this is only test code i write him fast.

Comment: I think you should simplify your question and cut out the extraneous code...strip it down to just the thing you're having trouble with.  Having a bunch of weird stuff like an else that can never be reached...makes it hard to even know what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Except in rare instances you don't need to push js via php and it increases a lot the complexity and instability of the code please create a separate js file. Furthermore `<script type="text/javascript" src="c.php"></script>` is incorrect because you have a type text/javascript and as source a php file. Maybe you meant c.js?